# Inner product on homogenous polynomials of degree $d$ over a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products, tensors

I was studying some definition about norm and distance on vector spaces, and I crossed this theorem:

Let $q:W \times W \to \mathbb{K}$ be a fixed inner product on vector space $W$, then there is a unique inner product on $Sym^d W $ (homogenous polynomials of degree $d$ over $W$), such that
$$Q:Sym^d W \times Sym^d W \to \mathbb{K}, \ \ Q(f^d,g^d)=q(f,g)^d.$$
I know that the difinition of $Q(f,g)$ is given by:
(we know there is coresspondance between homogenous polynomials of degree $d$ over $W$ and symmetric tensor of order $d$)

Consider a symmetric tensor $f\in Sym^dW$, it may be seen in coordinate systems as
$$f =   \sum_{|\alpha|=d}{d \choose \alpha}f_{\alpha} x^{\alpha},$$
where
$\alpha = (\alpha_1, \dots , \alpha_n) \in \mathbb{Z}^n_{\geq 0}$, $|\alpha| \ \  \colon= \alpha_1 + \cdots + \alpha_n$, $x^{\alpha} \ \  \colon= x_1^{\alpha_1} \dots x_n^{\alpha_n}$ and ${d \choose \alpha} \ \  \colon= \frac{d!}{{\alpha_1}! \dots{\alpha_n}!}$ is multinomial coefficient. Then for $f, g \in Sym^d W$, the inner product is defined as
\begin{align*}
  Q(\sum_{|\alpha|=d}{d \choose \alpha} f_{\alpha} x^{\alpha},\sum_{|\alpha|=d}{d \choose \alpha} g_{\alpha}x^{\alpha}) \ \  \colon=  \sum_{|\alpha|=d}{d \choose \alpha}f_{\alpha}g_{\alpha} = \sum_{|\alpha|=d} \frac{d!}{{\alpha_1}! \dots{\alpha_n}!}f_{{\alpha_1} \dots{\alpha_n}}g_{{\alpha_1} \dots{\alpha_n}}.
  \end{align*}
This definition holds the inner products' conditions (it is easy to check). Now I am stuck on proving $Q(f^d,g^d)=q(f,g)^d$.

Any comment and guidance are highly appreciated.

Comment: "Let $q\colon W \times W \to \mathbb{K}$ be a fixed inner product on vector space $W$ (homogenous polynomials of degree $d$ over $W$), then ..." doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thank you. I have edited the question.

Comment: No, you don't know $q(x_i,x_j)=\delta_{ij}$.  Instead, note that $\operatorname{Sym}^d W$ is spanned by elements of the form $w^d$, $w\in W$.

Comment: I may be wrong about them,, I will be grateful if you correct me or add anything helpful.

Comment: (Note additional comments from MO, https://mathoverflow.net/q/391561/88133)